# ValueError: Received incompatible tensor with shape (62, 128) when attempting to restore variable with shape (1, 128) and name lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0

Tags: python, time-series

I'am trying to tune hyperparameter for a LSTM model (time series) but I'am getting this error. I really don't understand why I'am gettin this.

Here is the code

```
data = df.filter(['Close'])
dataset = data.values
training_data_len =math.ceil( int((len(dataset) * .80))) # We are using %80 of the data for training
training_data_len
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
scaled_data

train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(30, len(train_data)):
  X_train.append(train_data[i-30: i, 0])
  y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

  if i <= 30:
    print(X_train)
    print(y_train)
    print()

len(X_train)

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

X_train.shape


X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)) # we make it like pros. it wanna say "np.reshape(X_train, (2083, 60, 1))"
X_train.shape
y_train.shape
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - 30 : , :]
#Create the data sets X_test and y_test
X_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len : , :]
for i in range(30, len(test_data)):
  X_test.append(test_data[i-30 : i, 0])

X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
y_train=np.reshape(y_train,([y_train.shape[0],1]))

def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(hp.Int('input_unit',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32),return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
    for i in range(hp.Int('n_layers', 1, 4)):
        model.add(LSTM(hp.Int(f'lstm_{i}_units',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(hp.Int('layer_2_neurons',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32)))
    model.add(Dropout(hp.Float('Dropout_rate',min_value=0,max_value=0.5,step=0.1)))
    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation',values=['relu', 'sigmoid'],default='relu')))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['mse'])
    return model
tuner= RandomSearch(
        build_model,
        objective='mse',
        max_trials=2,
        executions_per_trial=1
        )

tuner.search(
        x=X_train,
        y=y_train,
        epochs=20,
        batch_size=64,
        validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
)

best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
```

ValueError: Received incompatible tensor with shape (62, 128) when attempting to restore variable with shape (1, 128) and name lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0.

How can I get over it?

How can I get over it?

Where is my mistake?

Comment: My data contains 2181 values as a univariate time series.